# output on the same page and not on the other page

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

guys sorry for being so noob but im still starting yet with my php, what im trying to do is to do is to out put the result on the same page .

```
<html>

<body>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$button=$_POST['button_validate'];

if(isset($button)){

   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   $text=$_POST['text_validate'];

   if(empty($text)){
       echo "your email must have at least 1 number";
   } else {
       echo "this is valid";
   }
} else {
?>
<form action="validate.php" method="post">

Validate text<input type="text" name="text_validate">

<input type="submit" value="Validate" name="button_validate">

</form>

<?php } ?>

</body>

</html>
```

but instead of showing the out put on the same page in makes a new page.. is there a code on how to output this on the same page or its just in the logic?

Comment: You should read something about AJAX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). Possible use case: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Also, you should accept some answers people have given you in the past, you're only at 20%.

Comment: You can also print your form again beneath the php code.

Comment: That's standard for normal HTML form submission. You can't get around it with standard form submission methods. You need to use AJAX calls, which means a completely different structure for your script.

Comment: Aside from AJAX he could also pass a variable through sessions and echo it on the page then reset the variable at the end of his page so it only shows up on the next reload. He could even set it up to store an array and display multiple errors/messages. Just another solution that might be simpler if he's just starting out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this in your form tag:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

then your data will be submitted to the same page. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your form, you have specified the action to be validate.php.

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
```

That means when you submit your form, your page will be processed by the page validate.php

If you can remove the action attribute and your page will be processed by your current page.

```
<form method="post">
```

It looks like you have some validation already set up on that page, so now when you submit your form, your php logic will be processed.

---

Also as Sheikh Heera mentioned, if you move your form out of the conditional tag, you can display your form after posting. In the example below I just removed the else clause, so they form will be displayed even if you submit the form. Not sure if you wanted this or not.

```
<body>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$button=$_POST['button_validate'];

if(isset($button)){

   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   $text=$_POST['text_validate'];

   if(empty($text)){
       echo "your email must have at least 1 number";
   } else {
       echo "this is valid";
   }
}
?>

<form method="post">

Validate text<input type="text" name="text_validate">

<input type="submit" value="Validate" name="button_validate">

</form>

</body>
```